Multispan cells in longtblr
I'm trying to use \SetCell to create multi-row cells in a longtblr environment. It's working very well, except in the first column, where the multispan options don't work - the cells remain unmerged.
I've searched the tabularray documentation, and can't find any indication of what might cause this. The simple examples in the docs (using tblr, not longtblr) work as advertised. The issue only seems to appear when using longtblr.
For clarity, in the example below, I'd like the "Air Intake Duct" cell to span 2 cells, and the "Fan/Blower 1" cell to span 3 cells.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption={FMEA for the Ventilation (Supply) System }
]{
colspec = { X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] },
width = \linewidth,
rowhead = 1
}
\textbf{Component Description} &
\textbf{Function} &
\textbf{Failure Mode} &
\textbf{Cause of Failure} \\
\hline\hline

\SetCell[r=2]{c}Air Intake Duct (From outside to inside) &
  \SetCell[r=2]{c}Provide a pathway for air from (outside) into the ventilation plant &
  Leakage of air along duct &
  Physical damage or degraded condition \\*
  \hline
  
 & & Blockage of duct & Physical damage \\
  \hline
  
\SetCell[r=3]{c}Fan/blower 1 &
  \SetCell[r=3]{c}Drives airflow through the duct into the filter &
  Bearing failure &
  Wear out of bearings \\*
  \hline
  
 & & Blade damage & Cracking or mechanical wear & & \\*
  \hline
  
 & & Motor failure & Winding short circuit \\*
  \hline

\end{longtblr}

\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SE!
You have two ampersands in row before last to much. Removing them  you will get the following result:

Is it what you after?
The MWE (Minimal Working Example), which produce above table is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption={FMEA for the Ventilation (Supply) System }
                ]{colspec = { *{4}{X[c]} },
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                  hline{2-Z}={},    vline{2-Y}={},
                  rowhead = 1
                }
Component Description
    &   Function
        &   Failure Mode
            &   Cause of Failure                        \\
    \hline
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Air Intake Duct (From outside to inside) 
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    Provide a pathway for air from (outside) into the ventilation plant 
        &   Leakage of air along duct 
            &   Physical damage or degraded condition   \\
    &   &   Blockage of duct 
            &   Physical damage                         \\
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    Fan/blower 1 
    &   \SetCell[r=3]{c}    Drives airflow through the duct into the filter 
        &   Bearing failure 
            &   Wear out of bearings                    \\
    &   &   Blade damage 
            &   Cracking or mechanical wear             \\ % <--- here was 2 & to much
    &   &   Motor failure 
            &   Winding short circuit                   \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}

In code I made some small changes in table preamble which enable to remove all \hlines in table body.

Thank you!. I spent a long time looking in the wrong place for the problem. Clearly just needed a second set of eyes on it.
Is there any tool or method that would have highlighted this issue for me? One of the problems I have with LaTex is trying to fix weird issues like this, where the problem is not where you might expect it to be.

Most helpful is experiences . For most of text writing nowadays editors has good support for marking delimiters and environments, but for writing of tables, which are very demanding tasks, especially if their structure is complex (containing multi row and multi column cells), many people use tables generators available on the web (but generating code is usually not very clear). I help myself with structured way of writing in editor as you can observe in my MWE (Minimal Working Example).
